# Truncating tile cache outside bounding box using GeoWebCache

Tags: extents, geowebcache, tilecache

Is there a way to truncate all cached tiles outside of a specified bounding box, whilst leaving the cached tiles inside a bounding box untouched?

We have a nationwide system but it would be useful to remove all cached content outside of a bounding box whilst leaving the cached tiles inside the bounding box in situ. This would allow us to just reseed the cached content inside the bounding box when the mapping layers are updated.

Comment: You should be able to construct 4 boxes that fill the tiled area around the bbox you are interested in - again feel free to contribute code or examples for the docx

Comment: Thanks, that is an idea, i can try that. I am sorry i am not skilled in writing code so could not help in that respect.

Comment: You can always hire someone to help with the money you saved by using open source